# How to fix error with FindGameObjectsWithTag Unity2D C#

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a button which makes 2 gameobjects and they both have the tag "Card". In one of my script i have a List which holds the items spawned from the button.

```
for (int i = 0; i < UserCards_OnPlay.Count; i++)
{
     ObjectHolder = UserCards_OnPlay[i];

     ValueHolder = ObjectHolder.GetComponent<NewCard>().Card_WorkingValue;

     UserHandScore = UserHandScore + ValueHolder;
}
```

My problem is that when i print out the handscore it only takes the value of the second card in the list.It just misses out the first card.If i spawn anymore cards it works normally.

The buttons creates both objects .It uses 2 different subs from the same script.

Any solutions thanks.

Comment: The button creates 2 object but the code only takes 1 so I am not sure how to solve the problem

Comment: Can you provide a working example? Show the items that are in your list, and show how you are printing the resulting value for UserHandScore.

Comment: how do i show images?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ASpltDa

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/713c0dU

Comment: if i place the Debug.log in the loop it adds the first 2 cards properly .But if i add anymore cards to the scene it adds all their values over again .

Comment: You should not use a `for` loop like this. The correct way would be a `foreach(var card in UserCards_OnPlay)`. This won't solve your problem, but #goodPractice.

Comment: Additionally, your code snippet contains some globals, so you should show us their declarations and initial states.

Comment: i will figure this out Np .Thanks for the help